# Generating vineyard's rows in a polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, polygon, line

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate line (the distance between each one is 2 meters) in a polygon?

Comment: I'm working with ArcGis 10. The objective is to know how many lines/rows fit in the polygon, but with a determinated orientation and distance between lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Create Fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) tool to create a grid that will fill up your polygon. Input the height and width at 2m and set the number of rows and columns to 0 - this way it will fill up the polygon entirely. Set the template to your polygon

After that, you can start an [Edit Session](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000005p000000) and simply select either the vertical or horizontal rows and delete them. The easiest way to do that would be to select the features inside the attribute table. All horizontal rows should be sequential; likewise with vertical.

Finally, [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) the lines by the same polygon to remove the extras.

As you can see on the right side of #4, the lines don't quite extend all the way, so you should slightly increase the extents of Fishnet in all directions to correct this.

[image]